# Sharepoint 2013 - show edit to admin only

Tags: 2013, javascript, css

I hope this has not been asked before (I did a few search's on here first).

I need to be able to only show the Blue & Grey SharePoint Bars to admins - for all other users I want to be able to hide this. I can happily hide this completely with CSS, but need to have it easily visible to a select group of admins

Comment: By Blue and Grey SharePoint Bars, do you mean ribbon?

Comment: Hi @AsadRefai yes the ribbon, I can easily do this with CSS, i want to hide this dependent on role

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to modify the masterpage you can drop CSS to hide the ribbon conditionally using an `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`, just use the `ManageWeb` string - [How to use SPSecurityTrimmedControl to check if current user has edit rights to current page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/how-to-use-spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-to-check-if-current-user-has-edit-rights-to)

Comment: Hi @James Love, thank you for shareing the link; is this something you have tried personally? Do you know if this works for SP13?

Comment: It definitely works, I use it to conditionally load a CSS file when I want to hide ribbon options (not 100% security guaranteed, but at least it hides the option, and targeting specific ribbon actions are easy in CSS). Hiding the whole ribbon I haven't tried though.